# How do I repeat two variables twice?

Tags: python

```
first=input('hello what is your name?' )
second=input('Thanks whats your surname? ')
x=first,second
print(x*3)
```

I've tried this but it does repeat it 3 times but it also include the brackets and the commas

Comment: Show your expected output.

Comment: `x` is a tuple. `print` shows a string representation of the tuple, but it appears you want a specific string *based* on the tuple.

Comment: If you want x as a string rather than a tuple, you would be better combining them with some control as to the format of x. `x = f'{first} {second}'` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
first=input('hello what is your name?' )
second=input('Thanks whats your surname? ')
x=first,second
print(' '.join(x*3))
```

Try this hopefully it would give output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going for this

```
x = 'First','Second'
print(( str(x[0]) + str(x[1])) *3)
```

Output

> FirstSecondFirstSecondFirstSecond